# How do I turn up the brightness on my MacBook without being able to see the screen or use shortcuts?

Tags: macbook-pro

The screen brightness keys stopped working on my MacBook. So I went to preferences to turn down the brightness. I accidentally turned down the brightness all the way and I can't see my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a flashlight to see enough of the screen to turn the slider up. After thinking about it I realized I could have plugged in an external monitor as well.